Each row getting more misaligned during LVP install
I'm working on installing LVP in my basement. The LVP has a tongue and groove on the long side and a lock mechanism on the short side. As I'm working my way through the rows, if one plank is a tiny bit off then where that one touches the one next to it at the seam, then the board of the next row gets pushed a bit out of alignment from whatever one before it was slightly lower. As the rows go on, this tiny bit of misalignment is perpetuating and getting larger. I'm not sure how to handle it, I tried my very best to keep everything aligned but there's zero tolerance. I'd have to take everything up to try to get them perfect. I thought about trying to plane down the edge of a piece so it wasn't sticking below at the seam to push the next board off, but I can't really plane it because the locking mechanism would still be off. A tapping block won't help because one side taps in but the the other side sticks out.
Any ideas?



This happens when one plank is not tapped hard enough to anchor it to the next plank. It can look and feel like it is fully snapped in but it is not. I cut a 6 inch piece and use it as the block to tap ( sometimes a hard rap) one piece to the other. A good square edged tapping block is essential. If you do not have the installation kit go get one.
The most difficult part is starting the first 2 or 3 rows.  It can take 2 people. One to stand and anchor the row from moving, while the next row is installed. And always stagger the ends by at least 8 inches or the minimum recommended by the manufacturer.
I sometimes do most of 3 rows away from the wall and then slide the completed floor to the wall, leaving the required 1/4" gap with spacers.

A scrape section of the flooring will protect the edges as you are tapping it in tight.

I have a tapping block and tried everything you recommend already. I'm on row 18 or so at this point and can't pin point exactly where things started getting off track. Is the best way forward to just take everything apart and start again?

If you don't have a properly straight start, yes. Gaps should not be ignored at any stage. They must be dead tight. Use custom-cut spacer blocks against the wall at the start (after assembling 3 rows) to support further work. Be very gentle when you disassemble or you'll break things. Small movements, gentle swings.
